# Adding mutiple war with identical jars and common persistence unit in a EAR

Tags: ear

I need help on the design issue of an EAR. I have working knowledge of the WAR files but i am a novice when it comes to dealing with an EAR file.

I have 4 maven based projects -

```
common (JAR, containing common utilities, domain object and JPA/Hibernate based DAOs)
core (WAR, dependent on the common project)
front (WAR, dependent on the common project)
back (WAR, dependent on the common project)
```

I simply have 3 main WAR projects which using almost identical set of JAR files (Spring, Hibernate, Struts etc) and DAO layer.

Question 1: How can i package my project into an EAR using Eclipse IDE?

Question 2: How can i ensure that i do not have duplicate copies of identical JAR files?

Question 3: How can i have my DAO Layer (Hibernate) to be shared by all three web projects in a very efficient manner?

Question 4: Is this a good design?

I would be very greatful if you can please provide some help on this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use Maven
see on maven-ear-plugin : [Documentation here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/)

In your case you have to add dependency to your common jar in your ear and dependencies to your common jar in your wars as "provided".
then add webmodules to your ear and specify the defaultLibBundleDir like `<defaultLibBundleDir>/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>`